# behavior of operational amplifier at 0V

Tags: operational-amplifier

I measured the turn-on and turn-off behavior of an LM741 and found a weird phenomenon I cannot explain myself.
I built an inverting amplifier with an amplification of 10.

Why is there such a weird kink just before the output crosses 0V?
[image: CH2: output; CH1: input]
(CH2: output; CH1: input)
[image: CH2: output; CH1: input]
(CH2: output; CH1: input)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic would be very helpful. The 741 was on the market in the 1980's and has poor performance compared to what we have today.

Comment: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/53589/FAIRCHILD/LM741.html

That's the datasheet I used. It also includes the internal schematics.My circuit itself is a simple inverted amplifier with 560 Ohms and 5.6 kilo Ohms.

Comment: Does this help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgodYtiD_F0 ?

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar

That's exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know this is called "crossover distortion" so I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just look at the graphs in the data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You are observing the slew-rate limited output of the amplifier to a step input (~0.5V/us output slew).

You shouldn't expect it to behave linearly under those conditions.